# ocfs2 and packemaker without ocf:pacemaker:o2cb

Tags: pacemaker, ocfs2

In ubuntu 16.04 ocfs:pacemaker:o2cb not work anymore but i cant find any document that describe ocfs2 with packeamker without ocf:pacemaker:o2cb
I have drbd device and work fine with pacemaker, but ocfs tools dont aware pcmk cluster:

```
# mkfs.ocfs2  -T mail --node-slots 2 --label ocfs2_fs   --cluster-
stack=pcmk --cluster-name=debian  /dev/drbd1  
mkfs.ocfs2 1.6.4
Cluster stack: pcmk
Cluster name: debian
NOTE: Selecting extended slot map for userspace cluster stack
Overwriting existing ocfs2 partition.
mkfs.ocfs2: Unable to access cluster service while initializing the cluster
```

my cluster status:

```
# pcs status
Cluster name: debian
Last updated: Wed Oct 18 17:43:12 2017      Last change: Wed Oct 18 
14:45:32 2017 by root via crm_resource on testsvr1
Stack: corosync
Current DC: testsvr1 (version 1.1.14-70404b0) - partition with quorum
2 nodes and 10 resources configured

Online: [ testsvr1 testsvr2 ]

Full list of resources:

 Clone Set: WebSite-clone [WebSite]
     Started: [ testsvr1 testsvr2 ]
 Clone Set: WebFS-clone [WebFS]
     Stopped: [ testsvr1 testsvr2 ]
 Master/Slave Set: WebDataClone [WebData]
     Masters: [ testsvr1 testsvr2 ]
 vbox_stonith   (stonith:fence_vbox):   Started testsvr2
 Clone Set: dlm-clone [dlm]
 Started: [ testsvr1 testsvr2 ]
```

Comment: I do believe you're going to want o2cb managed by the cluster. Perhaps the better question to ask is why is o2cb broke in ubuntu 16.04? What errors does it give you? Can we correct those?

Comment: I found two thread in ubuntu that describe , did not need ocf:pacemaker:o2cb anymore. And one thread that said use lsb:o2bc instead in ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: ocf:pacemaker:o2bc give "not install" error

Comment: "Not installed" generally means that either the software is not installed, or more commonly, some configuration or component is missing.

Using a LSB type resource is valid, assuming the init script is fully LSB compliant, but you're not even using that in your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks To @Doc my problem resolved with lsb:o2cb

```
pcs resource create o2cb lsb:o2cb \
  op monitor interval="10" timeout="30" \
  op start interval="0" timeout="120" \
  op stop interval="0" timeout="120" \
  clone o2cb clone-max=2 clone-node-max=1
```

Comment: but still I dont understand why dlm service is used in all the documents and when can used mkfs.ocfs --cluster-stack=pcmk